# I made a website but, webpage is not displaying correctly

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, host

So I built a website from scratch and am really happy about it. I wanted to make it a live version, so I looked for a web hosting company online. I use hostinger.com for my web hosting, however I'm not getting the results I'm looking for.

**This is the finish product I made:**
[image of my index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPxvU.png)

**and this is the results I get after I uploaded it to my web hosting provider:**
[image from live web host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0laIf.png)

So hostinger has different options for how to upload your website. And I use git because it is easy to use. *Now the problem is I don't know if my code is the problem or my web hosting provider.*

Thank you for your help in advance.
You can check the website: ***https://johnmcondino.com***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the website is loading properly now.

Please press ctrl + F5 on windows. May be due to cache assets are not loading.